# How to run our python scripts utilizing our device's GPU?

Tags: computer-vision, python, yolo, gpu, opencv

My laptop has NVIDIA GeForce GTX1650 GPU. I want to utilize this GPU to run my Python script. Any help in the form of code would be really helpful. I mean tried researching this so much but I couldn't find.

Basically I am looping over all the frames of a video and at each frame I am using yolov8s-pose model to detect the keypoints. So since it is running on my CPU, it is very slow. So, that is the reason I need to know how to utilize my device's GPU to run it. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is going to depend on the library you use. In general, the term you should google is Cuda along with your GPU. In TensorFlow I have used things like [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu)
and I would recommend looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible) and [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/installing-tensorflow-cuda-cudnn-for-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1650-ti-onwindow-10-99ca25020d6c).

Comment: Awesome! I was able to use the GPU now. Thank you.

Comment: This is a programming question. **Programming questions are off-topic**. Please, stop answering questions that are off-topic. If you're not familiar with the on-topic page, this is the perfect time to do it: https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic